# XML Attribute Values C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, rest, soap

I am trying to retrieve the value of two XML attributes and having a hard time using Xelement. 
Basically I am getting an API response that has uses the same attribute naming convention for two different values.

This is the response I am getting back after making the call.

```
    -<ResponseData>    
        <Type value="7" id="Level"/>    
        <Type value="67.80" id="Score"/>    
    </ResponseData>
```

I want to set the two values to two different variables. level & score. I have the fulling code however I keep getting back a null reference error.

```
var xmlResponse = XElement.Parse(response);
var level = "";
var score = "";
if(xmlResponse.Attribute("id").Value == "Level")
{
    level = (string) xmlResponse.Attribute("value");
}

if(xmlResponse.Attribute("id").Value == "Score")
{
    score = (string) xmlResponse.Attribute("value");
}
```

I want my two variables to be set to the values I get back from the API call.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note, if this is a SOAP service with a WSDL, have you tried letting Visual Studio scaffold it?

So you have to think about it this way.. your now parsed `XElement` is a `ResponseData` object, which has a collection of `Type` objects in it now, and each `Type` object has a `value` and `id` attribute, which means you need to find the right `Type` entry for each value you're looking for. EG:

```cs
string data = @"<ResponseData>    
        <Type value=""7"" id=""Level""/>    
        <Type value=""67.80"" id=""Score""/>    
    </ResponseData>";

var xmlResponse = XElement.Parse(data);

var levelElement = xmlResponse.Elements("Type")?
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("id")?.Value == "Level");
var scoreElement = xmlResponse.Elements("Type")?
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("id")?.Value == "Score");

int level;
double score;

level = int.Parse(levelElement?.Attribute("value")?.Value ?? "-1");
score = double.Parse(scoreElement.Attribute("value")?.Value ?? "-1");

Console.WriteLine($"Score {score}; Level {level}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use?

```
-<ResponseData>    
    <Type Level="7" Score="67.80"/> 
</ResponseData>
```

Comment: I wish I could use that. However, it is a third party API I am using. That is just the response they're sending.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using XML that powershell knows how to work with.

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content C:\temp\xml.txt
$TypeNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Type[@id='Score']")
$TypeNode.Attributes["value"].Value
```